# In how many ways could you choose 5 cards with 2 hearts or 3 spades?

Tags: combinatorics

For all I know that there are $52$ cards $13$ of every type. So we can choose $2$ hearts in $\binom{13}{2}$ ways and $3$ spades in $\binom{13}{3}$ ways, so we can choose both in $\binom{13}{2}\cdot\binom{13}{3}$, but what about either this one or this one but not both (OR)
I think since we have in the hearts case one way to choose the first two spots and $\binom{39}{3}$ ways for the rest, in the second case we one way for the last three spots and $\binom{39}{2}$ for the rest. Therefor we have $\binom{39}{2} + \binom{39}{3} - \binom{13}{2} \cdot \binom{13}{3}= 741 + 9139 - 22308$ which is negative so what did I do wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- Choosing $5$ cards such that there are exactly $2$ hearts can be done on $\binom{13}2\binom{39}3$ ways.
- $\mathsf P(A\cup B)=\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)-\mathsf P(A\cap B)$ (applying on OR)
- $\mathsf P(A\Delta B)=\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)-2\mathsf P(A\cap B)$ (applying on XOR)

Comment: why you multiply the last case by 2 !

Comment: Because we are dealing with XOR (not OR). Make a Venn diagram to understand.

Comment: I can't make it in this problem

Comment: You said: "not both", didn't you?

Comment: yeah but I thought that's or not xor so now I get confused

Comment: Well. Pick out the second hint for OR (if that's what you are after) and pick out the third if you are after XOR (i.e. OR but not both). Are you familiar with the rule in the second hint?

Comment: in (or) case the answer would be 13c2 . 39c3 + 13c3 .39c2 - 13c2.13c3 is that right

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: but for the xor case why did subtract the intersection twice is that mean that you added it three times but how

Comment: If I subtract once then I get $P(A\cup B)$. But what I want in the XOR case is the probability of $(A\cup B)-(A\cap B)$ (excluding "both"). So I must subtract $P(A\cap B)$ once again.

Comment: I tried to get from another example so consider we wanna know how many number divisible by 3 or 2 but not both, since 5 numbers by 2 and 3 numbers divisible by 3 and 1 number support two cases so we added it twice so when we subtract it once it still exist when we subtract it twice we the numbers that either divisible by 2 or but not both is that write @drhab

Comment: Yes. If $N_k$ denotes the number of numbers divisible by $k$ then $N_2+N_3-N_6$ are divivisible by $2$ or $3$. Here $N_6$ is subtracted to repair double counting. $N_2+N_3-2N_6$ are divible by $2$ or $3$ but not by both (i.e. by $6$). $N_6$ is subtracted once again to delete also the single counting.